# Limitar a 12 caracteres numéricos en formulario

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

¿ Cuál seria la mejor forma de limitar a solo 12 caracteres numéricos un `text field` en un formulario?

Hasta ahora tengo esto pero no me excluye caracteres especiales.

```
var cardnumber = $("#loyalcard").val();
if (cardnumber.length < 12) {
   $("#card_error").toggle();
   $("input#cardnumber").focus();
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Como se menciono en la respuesta anterior empleando el `input` de tipo  `number` se validaría pero no abarcaría totalmente si se escribe sobre ese `input`,

Para ese caso podría recurrir a `javascript` puro , además empleo el método [Slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice) para cortar la cadena en el caso de que sea mayor. *ejemplo con máximo 12 digitos)*

```js
var input=  document.getElementById('numero');
input.addEventListener('input',function(){
  if (this.value.length > 12) 
     this.value = this.value.slice(0,12); 
})
```

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="999999999999" id="numero">
```

Answer (score 5):

Si quieres validar caracteres numéricos, lo más sencillo es utilizar la etiqueta que está destinada a ello: `<input type="number">`.

Aquí un ejemplo de su uso:

```html
<form action="">
  Ingresa un número:
  <input type="number" maxlength="12" oninput="if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" /><i>(Máximo 12 dígitos)</i>
  <br><input type="submit">
</form>
```

---

Más información: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: La respuesta mas facil y sencilla de implementar

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar con esto, es una manera de lograrlo sin usar el `type="number"`:

```
$('#tuInput').on('keydown keypress',function(e){
    if(e.key.length === 1){ // Evaluar si es un solo caracter
        if($(this).val().length < 12 && !isNaN(parseFloat(e.key))){ /* Comprobar que
                                                                     * son menos de 12
                                                                     * catacteres y que
                                                                     * es un número */
            $(this).val($(this).val() + e.key); // Muestra el valor en el input
            /*
             * Aquí haces lo que quieras.
             */
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Para restringir todo caracter que no sea numérico y no sobrepase los 12 caracteres puede ser controlado en el evento `keypress` evaluando que el código de la tecla presionada `event.which` esté en el rango de los números del 0 al 9 ([referencia](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)).

```
$('input#cardnumber')
  .keypress(function (event) {
    // El código del carácter 0 es 48
    // El código del carácter 9 es 57
    if (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57 || this.value.length === 12) {
      return false;
    }
  });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input#cardnumber')
    .keypress(function (event) {
      if (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57 || this.value.length === 12) {
        return false;
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="cardnumber">
```