# ¿Cómo evitar que input de html permita seguir escribiendo a determinado número de caracteres?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validación

Deseo que mi `input` permita n número de caracteres y al pasarse no permitir seguir escribiendo, he intentado hacerlo borrando el ultimo carácter, pero haciendo test si dejo presionado una tecla y escribe más de la cuenta no hace nada.

```
$("#buscar-rol").keyup(function(e) {
    validar_Type_Text($("#buscar-rol").val(), regex.texto, true, 10, "buscar-rol");
});
```

Los parámetros enviados son:

1. Valor del `input`.
2. `JSON` con el `RegEx` a comparar.
3. `true` o `false` para limitar o no el campo de texto a n caracteres.
4. El número de caracteres permitido.
5. ID del elemento.

   ```
   const validar_Type_Text = (text, type, bool_length, length, campo) => {
   let campo_length = $(`#${campo}`).val().length;
   let campo_value = document.getElementById(`${campo}`);
   if (type) {
     if (campo_length > length) {
       campo_value.value = campo_value.value.substring(0, campo_length - 1);
     }
   } else {

   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Si le añades la propiedad Maxlenght a tu input,

Comment: Pudiera ser, pero para los propósitos que busco, no sería lo más recomendado, ya que creo sería trabajar manipulando el DOM para estar cambiando la longitud, creo que con parámetros pudiera ser más fácil

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo, limitar input a 6 caracteres máximo: `<input maxlength="6"/>`

Comment: en esa pregunta formulan tu caso sin tener que manipular el input: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80223/limitar-a-12-caracteres-num%C3%A9ricos-en-formulario